# How to interpret this type of dendrogram?

Tags: python, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I used agglomerative clustering on my data and tried to plot it in a dendrogram and this result came out. But I was stuck trying to understand how to interpret this... Why is it so one-sided? Does this say anything about how 'useful' this clustering method can be? Does it say anything about how similar my data are?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the structure of the data with some principal component analysis?